# Files uploaded to the local server. How to save file path and file name into the mysql database using jsp ?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have tried to upload the file into the c local drive its working but i have to insert that file name and file path to the MySql database. Below code written for store file into the c:local folder successfully but file path and file name are not storing into the database. please correct my code.

```html
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*,java.util.zip.*" %>
<%
String saveFile="";
String contentType = request.getContentType();
if((contentType != null)&&(contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)){
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
int byteRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
while(totalBytesRead < formDataLength){
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
totalBytesRead += byteRead;
}
String file = new String(dataBytes);
saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
int pos;
pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
File ff = new File("C:/UploadedFiles/"+saveFile);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();
%>
<br>
<%out.println(saveFile);%>
<%
Connection connection = null;
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "12345");
psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into file_upload(file_path,file_name,category,tags) values(?,?,?,?)");

psmnt.setString(1, ff.getPath());
psmnt.setString(2, ff.getName());

int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
if(s>0){
System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
}
else{
System.out.println("Error!");
}
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
%>
```

Comment: i think missing bind parameters for category and tags

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Also bind parameters for category and tags in prepaid statement

Comment: Try to use Servlets for business logic. This is not prefered in JSP

Comment: please edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

Category and tags doesn't hold any value to be inserted into the database. There is no need of those to variables.
  Follow this code below :

```
psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into file_upload(file_path,file_name) values(?,?)");
```